# Parse.com Analytics not showing

Tags: parse-platform, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to connect to `Parse.com` 's `REST-API` via `NSURLConnection` to track AppOpened metadata.

I get `200 OK` back from the API and the headers are the same to the cURL headers but my API calls are not being represented in the data browser on `Parse.com` . Is `NSURLConnection` doing something silly I don't know of? API response is the same but one request gets represented while the other one isn't.

NSLog output:

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7ff5eb331ca0> { URL: https://api.parse.com/1/events/AppOpened } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "*";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Length" = 3;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sun, 04 Jan 2015 22:42:54 GMT";
    Server = "nginx/1.6.0";
    "X-Parse-Platform" = G1;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.019842";
} }
```

cURL output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 04 Jan 2015 23:03:51 GMT
Server: nginx/1.6.0
X-Parse-Platform: G1
X-Runtime: 0.012325
Content-Length: 3
Connection: keep-alive

{}
```

It's the same output. What am I doing wrong? Has anyone experience with this?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you're using iOS you can probably achieve the same result with a much simpler call to `[PFAnalytics trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions:@{}];`

Comment: yeah. But I don't want to ship the framework. I just want to call the REST API to get simple tracking data. The Framework is way overkill

Comment: Is it not showing up when you create a custom breakdown or are you expecting it in the default breakdown labeled "App Opens"?

Comment: No. When you go into your events tab under Analytics you can set custom events that should be represented in the graphs. When I choose AppOpened new API calls to that event from my app are not represented (not count). Calls via cURL work though. And I get the exact same headers 200 OK etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Parse was showing funny API keys the moment I copied them out of the cURL example they provide in their lovely docs. Don't know whose analytics I screwed over but I'm terribly sorry and it wasn't my fault!

Always copy your API keys out of [Your-Parse-App-Name]->Settings->Keys

It probably was just a stupid glitch that happened on the Server.